# An argument that can be a combination of enum.IntFlag

Tags: python, enums, python-typing

Given an `enum.IntFlag`:

```
class Flag(enum.IntFlag):
    FOO = 1
    BAR = 2
    QUX = 4
```

Can I express a type that says "Flag or any combination of Flags"?

```
def func(accepts: CombinationOf[Flag]):
    ...
```

such that all these would be valid:

```
func(Flag.FOO)
func(Flag.FOO | Flag.BAR)
```

but this one for instance would not:

```
func(8)
```

Comment: Just [`accepts: IntFlag`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=b145973ea52318b347e0ed34e08bf25d)?

Comment: I edited the question, I had a typo there in `CombinationOf[IntFlag]` which clearly should read `CombinationOf[Flag]`. Would `accepts: Flag` allow for `Flag.FOO | Flag.BAR` (which is 3) to be accepted and `8` not to be accepted (which can not be created from combining `Flag` elements)?

Comment: [Yes](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=6b86b03651ea99541f8b79cd8746fc62), though all literal `int`s won't pass type checking (including, say, 1 | 2 | 4 = 7). Does that work for you?

Comment: `Flag.FOO | Flag.BAR` already gives a `Flag`, so just `Flag` should work - that's the point of `enum.{Int,}Flag`, [_"Flag members support the bitwise operators `&` (AND), `|` (OR), `^` (XOR), and `~` (INVERT); the results of those operators are members of the enumeration."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Flag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `accepts: Flag`. `IntFlag` is a subclass of `enum.Flag` which supports bitwise operations between its members:

> `Flag` members support the bitwise operators `&` (AND), `|` (OR), `^` (XOR), and `~` (INVERT); the results of those operators are members of the enumeration.
>
> – [`enum.Flag` | docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Flag)

That said, the following [would work](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=6b86b03651ea99541f8b79cd8746fc62) as you'd expect:

```py
from enum import IntFlag

class Flag(IntFlag):
    FOO = 1
    BAR = 2
    QUX = 4

class NotFlag(IntFlag):
    LOREM = 8
    IPSUM = 16

def func(accepts: Flag) -> None:
    ...

func(Flag.FOO)             # Fine
func(Flag.FOO | Flag.BAR)  # Fine
func(NotFlag.LOREM)        # [...] incompatible type "NotFlag"; expected "Flag"
func(8)                    # [...] incompatible type "int"; expected "Flag"
```

Note that a normal/literal `int` cannot be typechecked since such checks require runtime data:

```py
func(1|2|4)                # [...] incompatible type "int"; expected "Flag"
func(7)                    # [...] incompatible type "int"; expected "Flag"
```